# In Blazor server, how to force all awaited tasks in OnInitializedAsync to complete before rendering page, avoiding any loading placeholders

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Here's my code:

```
public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

[CascadingParameter]
Task<AuthenticationState> AuthState { get; set; }

[Inject]
IAccountService AccountService { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var userId = (await AuthState).User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    Accounts = await AccountService.GetAccountsAsync(userId);
}
```

With its current state, my Razor component that lists data in `Accounts` will immediately throw an null reference exception because the page would render before my awaited async call in `OnInitializedAsync` finishes retrieving that data from a database.

I can fix this by initializing the `Accounts` collection with an empty one, then add some placeholder text/spinner in UI, which will be replaced by the data later when the awaited call completes.

I understand that by design Blazor wants us to work this way, to show user something while the page loads.

But what if I don't want to do this *for every single page*. On some pages I just want to show everything or nothing. A half second delay for data retrieval is okay.

I searched around and see this issue mentioned several times before in the past couple of years, but have yet to find a solution that would just make this page behave like a regular Razor page that would allow my initialization code to finish.

Your advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you only expect to solve this issue "page wide" (and not component wide) then you could try something like this. Wrap the @body with a cascading bool parameter and a container component which hides all inner content if the bool is false. Your pages could then all inherit a base class which sets the bool to true when the OnInitialize is completed. The parameter is set to false on page change. Then your pages only need to call its base OnInitialize last in its override. Not sure if this works but hope it can spark some ideas :)

Comment: just what I was looking for ! thanks:)